# Como traduzir uma instrução em hexadecimal na arquitetura intel x86 para assembly?

Tags: assembly

Como fazer isso olhando apenas os valores hexadecimais de um endereço?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: A Intel disponibiliza no site material sobre instruções de processador (linguagem de máquina) para download. E até um tempo atrás mandavam pelo correio para a casa da pessoa. De lá dos EUA. Não sei a página da documentação dos processadores agora.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa de um [*disassembler*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desmontador). Tentar fazer na mão é um trabalho árduo, arriscado e problemático, além de precisar de um livro para explicar. [Tem um *online*](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/).

Comment: vlw mais queria saber como fazer isso manualmente mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Veja os opcodes de cada instrução no instruction-set do 80x86. Há uma tabela mapeando cada instrução com o seu opcode em Hexa. Ao identificar o OpCode veja qual instrução em assembly corresponde a ela.

O maior problema é saber se o que você está olhando num binário é uma instrução ou um operando ou um operador ou um dado no Data Segment. Só terá êxito se tiver certeza do que está olhando é realmente o OpCode.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Original_8086.2F8088_instructions